# How to split a string in java and include the delimiter

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

I want to split this string "AHHHAAAAARTFUHLAAAAAHV" using a delimiter "AAAA"  and save it to an array including the delimiter. (desired output: [AHHHA, AAAA, RTFUHLA, AAAA ,HV]). I have the following codes below but the output is not the same to my desired output.

```
  String y = "AHHHAAAAARTFUHLAAAAAHV";
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y.split("((?<=AAAA)|(?=AAAA))")));
```

OUPUT:
      [AHHH, A, AAA, A, RTFUHL, A, AAA, A, HV]

Comment: try `Arrays.toString(y.split("(?=AAAA[^A]|(?<=AAAA(?=[^A])))"))` ?

Comment: Your desired splitting rule is ambiguous. `AHHHAAAAA` could be split into either `AHHH, AAAA, A` or `AHHHA, AAAA`. What is your expected outcome for `AAAAAAAAA` (9 `A`s)? `AAAAA, AAAA`, or `A, AAAA, AAAA`, or ...?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh WOW! thank you that did the job! Thank you that helped a lot.

Comment: @Socowi I thought so. Im practically toying around the split function so i was confused. Btw thank you so much for the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`(?=AAAA[^A]|(?<=AAAA(?=[^A])))`](https://regex101.com/r/YZagl7/1)

`(?=AAAA[^A]` : look-ahead to match `AAAA` and a non `A` char

`|` :  or

`(?<=AAAA(?=[^A])))` : positive-look-behind to match `AAAA` with lookahead to make sure there is no `A` character

```
String y = "AHHHAAAAARTFUHLAAAAAHV";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y.split("(?=AAAA[^A]|(?<=AAAA(?=[^A])))")));
```

Output :

```
[AHHHA, AAAA, RTFUHLA, AAAA, HV]
```

Comment: Maybe [`(?=AAAA(?!A)|(?<=AAAA(?!A)))`](https://regex101.com/r/2wxBrA/1) is also good to use here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i have tested negative look ahead against mine but seems like they are taking little more time though they are surely concise

Comment: Actually, I believe they will work differently as well. Anyway, it is just in case.